# Why empty function returns true with object member call but false with variable?

Tags: php, function, if-statement, variables, is-empty

```
$pq_test        = pq( '.test' );
$pq_test_length = $pq_test->length;

if ( empty( $pq_test_length ) ) { // false
    return false;
}

if ( empty( $pq_test->length ) ) { // true
    return false;
}
```

Why do I have different result with calling `$pq_test` and with extracting variable?

Expected and correct *IF-statement* result needs to be - `false`.

`pq` - is a `phpQuery` core function|

PHP version = `7.2`

Comment: Prior to PHP 5.5 empty() only supported variables.  What version are you using?

Comment: What's `var_dump` of `$pq_test_length` and `$pq_test->length`?

Comment: Check out the UserContributed Note from Janci here:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php